# Kinesis: What is the direction in which data is read from a Shard when using LATEST vs TRIM_HORIZON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

In the AWS API for Kinesis, shard iterators have the parameter `ShardIteratorType` which accepts one of the following values:

> AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, AT_TIMESTAMP, TRIM_HORIZON,
>   LATEST

However, the AWS documentation for this is very poorly written, and hence my question, which is critical for understanding how Kinesis works:
When using each of the above listed iterator types, what is the direction in which data is read?

Is the data read from the record at the current pointer, to a record that was inserted **before** the current record; or is the data read from the record at the current pointer to a record that was inserted **after** the current record was inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the shard iterator api [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html)

We can see that the LATEST starts at the head of stream and works backwards, you get your newest record and proceed back to your oldest.

TRIM_HORIZON works in the opposite direction, you get the oldest data and proceed to your newest data.

The AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, and AT_TIMESTAMP are based on the concept of starting at a know place in the stream and moving sequentially. Sequentially at least based on  [sequence number](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html#sequence-number)  docs I believe this to mean moving in a trimming direction. ie, for least to greatest sequence number.

I hope some of that helps, LASTEST and TRIM_HORIZON make sense to me based on those docs, however I totally agree that AFTER/AT_SEQUENCE number are a bit confusing. If anyone has good edits on that, please comment on it.

Comment: "We can see that the LATEST starts at the head of stream and works backwards, you get your newest record and proceed back to your oldest." Any reference to docs to back this statement up?

Comment: If you read the third paragraph https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html it describes how the LATEST will get you the newest batches. There might be a spot where that is more explicitly stated.